# What files are left out of the tagged github zip?

Tags: github, git-tag

I had some issues with a deploy and has to revert back to a tagged version of the code.

When reviewing the changes between the the tagged code and the git code it had some changes like changelog.

Is there a list of exclusions for a zipped tag version of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If a file is tagged in `.gitattributes` as `export-ignore`, then it will not be included in the archive.  This is a feature of `git archive`, and GitHub uses `git archive` internally to generate archives.

There is no way to disable this feature, although if you were using `git archive` by hand, you could use `--worktree-attributes` to override these values and cause the files to be included.